# Specifying the Financial Institution Address for a Direct Bank Transfer

Tags: eft

I'm filling a Direct Bank Transfer form and they ask me for my Financial Institution Address. My question is, is this a local branch address, or bank headquarters?

Comment: Your best chance of an authoritative answer will be to ask whoever sent you the form. For someone here to have a chance of helping, you should at a minimum include the country/ies involved and probably the specific type of transfer. Having said that, in the UK my default position (without indicators to the contrary) would be the branch address where the account is (nominally) held.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are the sender in this transfer though you don't state that directly.

If you are the sender then the form you are filling out is your bank's form and if your bank is asking for the bank's
address then it must be your local branch. Why they ask for that is a bit of a mystery.

The transfer request must include all of the following information about the recipient - 
  Recipient name,
  Recipient full address,
  Recipient's bank name,
  Recipient's bank headquarters address, 
  Recipient's bank SWIFT Code also known as BIC (needed if this transfer is international),
  Recipient's bank routing ABA number (if recipient bank is in US),
  Recipient's account number

I have done a fair number of transfers, to myself at a different bank within the USA, to other people at other banks within USA and to other people internationally from the USA. All my transfers have been initiated online.